# get a gradient theme for entire flutter app

Tags: flutter, containers, gradient

how can i get a gradient theme for entire flutter app , is there any modification in theme data , also theme chaniging is need,
using container gradient is simple for one page but needed it for many

get a simple way to make flutter app UI gradient.

Comment: What exactly have you searched, what is it that you have tried and why does't it work? What exactly are you expecting? Your question needs some more detail.

Comment: @RajatShenoi How do you create an initial gradient lets say with the shades of orange, which can be changed with other color pallets like blue, green, pink etc?